# Getting Backbone model attributes using @key in handlebars

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I want to get Backbone model properties in Handlebar template.
I am passing `data` to the handlebar template which is nothing but a Backbone model.
Below is handlebar template I am using

```
<table class="basic">
<thead>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Value</th>
<th>Unit</th>
<th>Description</th>
</thead>
<form>
<tbody>
 {{#each sections}}
  {{#each this.entries}}
        <tr><td>{{this.name}}</td><td><input type="name" name={{@key}}/> value={{data.[@key]}} /></td><td>{{this.units}}</td><td>{{this.descrip}}</td></tr>
   {{/each}}
 {{/each}}
<tr>
 <td></td><td class="button" colspan="4"><button id="update">{{$ 'Update'}}</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</form>
</table>
```

Now here I want to show value for certain properties from `data` model into input field for which I am currently trying `data.[@key]` but not working.

Can anyone tell me what will be the right way to get backbone model property using this @key?

**UPDATE****

Now another thing I noticed here is if I use **{{data.any_property}}** out of each loop then its showing me proper value.
But if I use **{{data.any_property}}** inside each loop its not giving me proper value.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening ?

**EDIT****

I have post full template now.
Below is my **templateHelpers** function

```
templateHelpers: function(){
      helpers = {};
      helpers.sections = this.sections;
      helpers.data = this.model.toJSON();
      return helpers;
    },
```

Below is json which I want to render through handlebars

```
{
    "sections": [{
        "entries": {
            "any-key1": {
                "name": "Name",
                "units": "%",
                "descrip": "desc"
            },
            "any-key2": {
                "name": "Name",
                "units": "%",
                "descrip": "desc"
            },
            "any-key3": {
                "name": "Name",
                "units": "%",
                "descrip": "desc"
            },
        },
        "name": "Entry name",
        "description": "Entry description."
    }, {
        "entries": {
            "any-key1": {
                "name": "Name",
                "units": "%",
                "descrip": "desc"
            },
            "any-key2": {
                "name": "Name",
                "units": "%",
                "descrip": "desc"
            },
            "any-key3": {
                "name": "Name",
                "units": "%",
                "descrip": "desc"
            },
        },
        "name": "Entry Name",
        "description": "Entry Description."
    }]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [model.toJSON()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) on the model? Either use it when you pass the model into the template or right in the template with data.toJSON().

Comment: yes but data.[@key] doesn't seems to work

Comment: What does `this.entries` look like? A quick demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would be helpful.

Comment: I agree with mu. What is the context for `this`? It sounds like there might be a conflict there. I'd like to see more of the code. Particularly the code that calls the template and passes the model.

Comment: @muistooshort : I have posted full template now. 
I tried with ../../data and seems its working when I use ../../data.any_property but not working for ../../data.[@key].